# elasticsearch 5.x truncating keyword value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a very lengthy string to be indexed in elasticsearch. I am using field type "keyword" (as I need to do aggregate on it) for indexing this field. The underlying lucene engine has a byte limit of 32766. Is there any option,plugin etc in elasticsearch to truncate the characters after this length automatically.

I don't want to do truncation programmatically, I want elasticsearch to handle this truncation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should never aggregate on such long fields. You could use an ingest processor (i.e. the [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/script-processor.html) to reduce the field length before indexing).

Comment: Script processor can be used only in search query. How do you use it in indexing? Can you please give an example